# How to find old article "B. R. McGarvey, Transition Metal Chemistry 3, 89 (1966)"

Tags: publications, citations, journals

I have encountered some experimental results on a molecule ($[V(H_2O)_6]^{2+}$) in various articles. However, the results are not original, and in each article they refer to "B. R. McGarvey, Transition Metal Chemistry 3, 89 (1966)". I have searched online, but I cannot seem to find that article. Does someone know a trick to find it rather than just doing a Google search?

Comment: Well, something is weird since Transition Metal Chemistry (https://link.springer.com/journal/11243/volumes-and-issues) started in 1976, and volume 3 in 1978 does not have an article by McGarvey. Web of Science finds no papers by McGarvey in Transition Metal Chemistry. However, a _book_ exists that is the likely hit, Transition Metal Chemistry; A Series of Advances; Volume 3
Carlin, Richard L. (Editor)
Published by Marcel Dekker, Inc, NY, 1966

Comment: And, my obligatory, go talk to your friendly neighborhood research librarian...

Comment: @JonCuster, you are correct in your first comment. Thank you for the help!